# Basic asp.net form with twitter bootstrap components

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Do you guys have an example of bootstrap componentes working on a basic asp.net form (with code behind on buttons, getting dropdown selected values and etc)?

I really don't know how to make it work.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What doesn't work? Bootstrap is just a collection of CSS styles. I can't see why that would break ASP.NET.

Comment: All of the Twitter stuff is HTML/CSS/JavaScript, so the server-side technology you use doesn't affect it.  Do you have an example of these components _not_ working?  We can potentially help with that.  Otherwise, Twitter has examples of the components working.

Comment: Actually i'm not saying that the componentes doesn't work. I just don't know how to make them work on a asp.net form. I mean, what should i do? Set the button style to "btn"? Check this tag, it's a server component provided by .net framework: "<asp:button id="Button1" runat="server></asp:button>". On the other hand, an bootstrap button in an simple html input. How can i call and asp.net onclick event on the button? Everything via javascript? Thank you very much.

Comment: The Twitter stuff, being all client-side, wouldn't be interacting with the `asp:Button` that you specify server-side.  It would be interacting with the `input` that actually gets rendered to the client.  So you'll need to either know or explicitly set what the client-side ID would be.  (Or identify the HTML element in some other way, if the Twitter stuff allows more complex selectors.)

Comment: @David I know the client-side ID of all components, and how they render on HTML, that's not the problem. What i want to know is how to interact with components using server-side methods, get their values and add onclick events to them. Thanks for you help!

Comment: @David - actually it won't work well with all the ASP.Net controls out of the box. E.g. ASP.Net checkboxes render as an input followed by a label. Bootstrap's selectors expect a label containing an input and a string.

Comment: You can use and implement a Input Adapter see CSS Adapter for more information (in codeplex)

Comment: @Leandro, Você sabia que Pedro Fernandes tem uma implementação quase completa de controles boostrap Twitter no Github: 
https://github.com/pmcfernandes/BootstrapControls

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As long as you have an understanding of how ASP.NET server controls render in HTML

**example:**

This server control:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Button 1" />
```

Renders to this HTML:

```
<input type="submit" class="btn" id="Button1" value="Button 1" name="Button1">
```

then you're on your way to using bootstrap with ASP.NET webforms

The `CssClass="btn"` is all you need to style the button with bootstrap.

Paste the markup below in your .ASPX page to see an example

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.4.0/bootstrap.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CssClass="btn" Text="Button 1" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**edit:**

You can turn any standard HTML control into a server control by adding `runat="server"` and then add click event handlers server side.

HTML:

```
<a id="actionLink" runat="server">Action</a>
```

Code-Behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    actionLink.ServerClick += new EventHandler(actionLink_ServerClick);
    ...
}

void actionLink_ServerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Rendered Anchor Tag:

```
<a id="actionLink" href="javascript:__doPostBack('actionLink','')">Action</a>
```

This should get you what you need to implement server clicks on those button dropdown and radio bootstrap controls.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect. But, what about a component that doesn't exists on asp.net framework? Such as this Button dropdowns (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns)? How can i add a onclick event calling a server side method? Or, how can i get this checkbox selected value on server side (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#buttons)? Thanks!

Comment: @LeandroFaria I've updated the answer, turning the `<button>` or `<a>` tags into server controls with `runat="server"` and adding event handlers on those controls should take you to the next step implementing those bootstrap controls.

Answer (score 0):

There's a nearly complete set of ASP.NET Bootstrap Controls available from Pedro Fernandes available on GitHub, not sure of the license though:

https://github.com/cr1t/BootstrapControls

It only supports version 2.3.0.  It shouldn't be difficult to convert it to 3.0.